# Python Texttable

Tags: python, syntax-error

I am trying to build a table for an exercise using texttable.

```
tab.add_row(row) = ["Match1", Team1_matches[1], Team2_matches[1], max(Team1_matches[1],Team2_matches[1])]
```

I am getting this:

```
  tab.add_rows(row) = ["Match1", Team1_matches[1], Team2_matches[1]]
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assigned the list of elements to `tab.add_row(row)`, that's why you got the `SyntaxError`

The correct way use `Texttable` is:

```
# create a list with the elements and assign it to row
row = ["Match1", Team1_matches[1], Team2_matches[1], max(Team1_matches[1],Team2_matches[1])]
# insert a row into table by invoking add_row() of the TextTable object tab.
tab.add_row(row)
```